# Combing Through Divs

Tags: jquery

I am trying to have the functions below cycle through a list of divs - so far I only have it set up to apply to one div (#two) and the nearest div. I understand that it needs to increment (i+++) where the first div (#one) will have i=0.

And yes, I am that new guy building my own bare bones slider.

```
function movedown() {
   $("#two").next().animate({height:'80%'}, 500);
   $("#two").animate({height: '20px'},500);
;}

function moveup() {     
   $("#two").prev().animate({height:'80%'}, 500);
   $("#two").animate({height: '20px'},500);
;}

$(function () {
   $('#up').click(moveup); 
   $('#down').click(movedown);
});
```

Comment: What's the problem? Perhaps, set up an example on jsfiddle.net.

Comment: No problem with the current code, but I have no idea on where to start with have the code built to scroll through all divs (not just div #two)

Answer (score 1):

give your divs ids like one two three as you are doing rite now.
then try this might help

```
function movedown() {
    for(var i=0; i<(no of divs);i++){
        $("#"+i).next().animate({height:'80%'}, 500);
        $("#"+i).animate({height: '20px'},500);
    }
 ;}
```

Comment: and the opposite of movedown, moveup, would simply replace .next() with .prev()?

function moveup() {
    for(var i=0; i<(3);i++){
        $("#"+i).prev().animate({height:'80%'}, 500);
        $("#"+i).animate({height: '20px'},500);
    }
 ;}

Comment: sorry when i add 'code' i cant even format my comments properly